# Cassandra not running. Gives connection refused

Tags: cassandra

Command: sudo service cassandra status

```
cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2020-02-06 19:27:40 IST; 1h 52min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cassandra.service

Feb 06 19:27:40 chaitra-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx systemd[1]: Starting LSB: distributed storage system for structured data...
Feb 06 19:27:40 chaitra-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed storage system for structured data.
```

Command: sudo nodetool status

```
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.
```

I dont know how to resolve this problem. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: is the cluster running? a service loaded and active does not guarantee this. You can verify that the cluster is healthy executing `nodetool status`, this should list all the nodes in the cluster, they should also be reported as `UN` (Up and Normal)

Comment: check the `system.log` first...

Comment: You shouldn't need to run `nodetool` as sudo.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I would try in this situation:
1) Check the network ports on the host

```
# netstat -nap | grep 7199 | grep LISTEN
```

You'll either want to run the above command as the cassandra owner (assuming cassandra started the process listening on 7199), or as root (so you can see anything that's listening on port 7199). If you get lines back, you'll be able to get the unix process id that's listening on port 7199 (the port that Cassandra uses for JMX by default). Validate that cassandra is the process listening on that port with:

```
# ps -ef | grep <pidFoundFromAboveCommand>
```

If it's cassandra (or dse if using datastax), then you're making progress. If not, then cassandra isn't running, or is using a different port that you'll have to specify when connecting.

If Cassandra is running and listening on port 7199, then depending on your cassandra.yaml configuration, in particular your listen_address, native_transport_broadcast_address, and native_transport_address, you may have to specify the host name. As you can tell, it's trying to connect to 127.0.0.1. You may have to specify the host in your nodetool command (and possibly the port if the JMX_PORT is different than 7199) to get it to work.

I can't remember the combination, but our configuration has native_transport_address = 0.0.0.0, native_transport_broadcast_address = "hostIP" and listen_address = "hostIP". That combination will allow you to not have to specify the hostname from the nodetool command.

The last thing you could check is whether or not firewalls are in the way of connecting to port 7199. As you're trying to use 127.0.0.1, it could possibly be iptables (firewalld) blocking that port, but in most cases is unlikely.